# Creating an SSRS report identifying database activity

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services

I'm trying to create a SQL query that tells if any new tables/views or SP's have been created for a particular month. So far getting the info on any new objects created has been the easy part

```
select SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) AS schema_name, 
       name AS objects_name, 
       create_date, 
       modify_date,
       type,
       so.type_desc,
       principal_id
from sys.objects so
where type in ('U','V','P')
and create_date > DATEADD(DAY, -30, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
```

What has been challenging is finding out who created or modified these artefacts. All online sources point to me having to create a trigger on the DB. Is there any query I can run to identify the responsible person.

NB:not the roles but the actual userid

Tried a bunch of queries including a trace:

```
DECLARE @RC int, @TraceID int, @on BIT
EXEC @rc = sp_trace_create @TraceID output, 2, N'C:\path\file'
SELECT RC = @RC, TraceID = @TraceID
-- Follow Common SQL trace event list and common sql trace
-- tables to define which events and table you want to capture
SELECT @on = 1
EXEC sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 128, 1, @on
-- (128-Event Audit Database Management Event, 1-TextData table column)
EXEC sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 128, 11, @on
EXEC sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 128, 14, @on
EXEC sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 128, 35, @on 
EXEC @RC = sp_trace_setstatus @TraceID, 1
GO
```

Comment: I don't think this is possible unless the objects where created recently in which case you can look in the schema changes history report (right-click the database in SSMS then reports/standard reports/schema changes history). You could run a trace when running this find out what system tables it is querying.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback and yes I've tried that and can successfully see who made changes but I don't know how to use that in a SSRS report...